# Are there any Fake File System frameworks for Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am introducing tests in a project that makes heavy use of IO operations (the file system, in this case). The system constantly opens/closes files, checks if files exist, deletes them, etcetera.

It soon became obvious that regular mocking wouldn't be of much use, as that would make my tests hard to set up and reason about. On the other hand, having a fake file system would be awesome, and I think, pretty easy to set up.

It seems the ruby guys did it again, and there's exactly what I am asking for in ruby: http://ozmm.org/posts/fakefs.html.

Is there anything remotely similar for Java?

Comment: It looks like one the application level this is easier to do in languages without a static type system. In Java, a File/FileInputStream/FileOutputStream always will refer to the underlying system's file system - if you don't patch the VM.

Comment: There are interfaces like [JavaFileManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaFileManager.html) or [FileSystemView](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html) which you could implement, but most programs won't use them.

Comment: @1st comment: I am well aware of that. I have currently replaced all the uses of File to a Filename of my own that only contain the file name as a string. All the IO logic was concentrated on a IFileSystem interface. The problem I am having is that it'd be still like a full day of work to implement the fake file system the way I needed it(with support for files + folders + hidden files + renames + getting only the path from a file name + ...) and testing it, to know it actually is right.

Comment: Since you mentioned Ruby in the OP, I would just like to add here that there is an equivalent in C# also, [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) which I've started using recently and is quite good.

Answer (score 59):

Google has an open-source, in-memory implementation of Java 7's FileSystemProvider. The [project is called jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs).

---

If you use Java 6 or earlier, there is an alternative: I've used [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) before to great success. It seems to be much like the custom FileSystemProvider another answerer mentioned is in Java 7.

It comes [pre-loaded](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html) with several file-system implementations: File, RAM, S/FTP, and Jar to name a few. I've also seen a [plugin for S3](http://code.google.com/p/vfs-s3/).

Comment: +1 to jimfs, which allowed me to test my code without a single change. (I used `Path` by accident)

Comment: Note that if you're working with a library that tries to take a path and do a `toFile` this is unsupported.

Answer (score 37):

In Java 6 and earlier it is difficult because classes like `File` and `FileInputStream` provide no way to dispatch to different "virtual file systems" in Java space.

In Java 7, there is support for virtual file systems; see [Developing a Custom File System Provider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html).  I don't know whether this will allow you to do what you want to do, but it is a good place to start looking.

---

> Meh. Being the fact that there doesn't seem to actually be any fake file system, I guess I'll just implement a minimal implementation by myself. I win nothing by using FileSystemProvider

Actually, you DO win by using FileSystemProvider:

- You implement something that (if released under an open source license) could be very useful to other people in your position, and for other purposes.
- You make it easier for yourself if you decide to switch to a FileSystemProvider that someone else might be working on right now.

Comment: Interesting, but as it seems I'd still have to implement the file system by myself, not that useful ;-(

Comment: At least it **allows** you to do that.  And as you yourself said - *"it would be easy to set up"*.

Comment: Meh. Being the fact that there doesn't seem to actually be any fake file system, I guess I'll just implement a minimal implementation by myself. I win nothing by using FileSystemProvider.

Comment: @devoured elysium - see my update.

Comment: +1 for recommending writing and open source-ing a solution

Comment: There's already an open-source solution for Java 1.4+: [Apache Commons VFS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11256516/4931).

Comment: @MichaelDeardeuff - I know that.  But you'll find that the standard SE classes like `File` and `FileInputStream` won't use VFS.  That would force the OP to write his production code so that his unit tests / mocking framework can use VFS ... which is a nutty idea.

Comment: @StephenC It's asking the OP to write his code so that it doesn't care where it's written to by using FileObject instead of File. This does not seem nutty to me: the storage location is just an implementation detail.

Comment: @MichealDeardeuff - You didn't understand what I said I think.  You are suggesting that the OP rewrite parts of his PRODUCTION CODE to use VFS ... with all of the overheads that that occurs (development cost, runtime performance hit, code complexity, etc) ... just so that he can use VFS in his unit tests.  IMO, that is nutty.  Or perhaps you'd like to explain to his PM why all that extra work a good idea.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder` from the [JUnit](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) package:

> The TemporaryFolder Rule allows creation of files and folders that are guaranteed to be deleted when the test method finishes (whether it passes or fails):

**Example:**

```
final TemporaryFolder testFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
testFolder.create();
final Path filePath = testFolder.newFile("input.txt").toPath();
final Path dirPath = testFolder.newFolder("subfolder").toPath();
```

Alternatively quit the `.toPath()` part:

```
final File filePath = testFolder.newFile("input.txt");
```

Comment: TemporaryFolder is not in-memory.

Answer (score 9):

You can abstract the use of `File` by using the intention of "somewhere to write data" by changing your API to use an `OutputStream` instead of a `File`, then pass the API a `FileOutputStream` in your production code, but pass it a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) from your tests. A `ByteArrayOutputStream` is an in-memory stream, so it's very fast and you can simply inspect its contents by using its methods - it's perfect for testing. There's also the corresponding `ByteArrayInputStream` if you want to *read* data.

File systems are generally pretty fast - unless you were doing a great deal of File I/O in your tests, I wouldn't bother.

Note that creating a java `File` object does *not* create a file on disk, ie the following code doesn't cause any change to disk:

```
File f = new File("somepath"); // doesn't create a file on disk
```

Comment: new File("something") won't create a file on disk but if you try to run almost any of its methods it will use the file system. Try new File("xyz").getAbsolutePath() to see what I mean..

Comment: I think people are assuming my main concern is speed. It is not.

Comment: i find it's always good practice to abstract away any resources like file systems (same way you would write a data access layer to the DB). this is usually achieved by writing an interface and a thin wrapper around the lowest level class. if you use dependency injection at the highest level of your program you can very easily propagate a mock file system (note it doesn't have to be using a mock framework, just a "dummy" implementation of the interface) through your application.

Comment: @devouredelysium `new File("xyz").getAbsolutePath()` does absolutely nothing whatsoever except return the path that the file *would* have *if* it existed. It doesn't change the file system; if the file doesn't exist, it still returns the String of the path and doesn't create a File. What did you mean by "see what happens"?

Comment: `File` is not final in my OpenJDK 7.

Comment: @DzmitryLazerka I don't know why I thought that... anyway, I think I've improved the answer.

Comment: @StephenC I don't know why I thought that it was final. I even went back to 1.3 docs to check, and nope. Anyway, thanks. It's a better answer now anyway IMHO (ByteArrayOutputStream)

Answer (score 6):

[Jimfs](https://github.com/google/jimfs), by Google, is an in memory NIO filesystem, that's great for tests.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to use your system's way of providing a file system based totally on RAM - [tempfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) on Linux, a [RAM disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk) on Windows.

Comment: I don't see how that would be any better than using the true file system (other than speed).

Comment: Yeah, speed (and disk wear) would be the main reason. Sorry, maybe I did misunderstand your goal.

Comment: My goal is to easy my testing. I am currently not concerned with performance.

Answer (score 4):

[MockFTPServer](http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/mockftpserver/fake/filesystem/FileSystem.html) appears to have a couple of Fake Filesystem implementations (Unix/Windows)

It looks like you can use these fake filesystem implementations quite seperately from any FTP concepts. I'm trying this now for exactly the same pursposes as you've outlined.

Comment: I'm using UnixFakeFileSystem. Working very well as a fake  implementation for my FileSystem abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

i'm not sure about specific frameworks, but a general approach in terms of OOP would be to write some abstracted layers on top of any file access code (interfaces galore!) and perhaps a facade to ease use of common operations. then you just mock one layer below the code you are currently testing and it then essentially a fake file system (or at least the code you're testing won't know otherwise).

if you look into using a dependency injection framework to handle this for you it will ease the ability to switch out components for a faked implementation of an interface. if you follow the patterns of inversion of control, passing in any dependencies into the constructor of the class you are testing this will also make for easy testing.

```
public interface IFileSystem {
   IFileHandle Load(string path);
   //etc
}

public class ClassBeingTested {
   public ClassBeingTested(IFileSystem fileSystem) {
      //assign to private field
   }

   public void DoSomethingWithFileSystem() {
       //utilise interface to file system here
       //which you could easily mock for testing purposes
       //by passing a fake implementation to the constructor
   }
}
```

i hope my java is correct, i haven't written java in a long while, but you will hopefully get the drift. hopefully i'm not underestimating the issue here and being overly simplistic!

of course this is all assuming you mean true unit testing, that is, testing the smallest possible units of code, and not an entire system. for integration testing a different approach is needed.

Comment: A fake file system needs to have logic of its own -- it's a file system like any other, but that only exists in memory. I'd like to avoid having to program myself such a file system.

Comment: what type of file system operations are you looking to imitate? locking of files? reading/writing? or simple stuff like opening files, checking directories exist, creating files?

Comment: Mostly simple operations that deal with checking whether the files are files or directories, if they exist, to create files, to delete files. This, of course, while supporting multiple folders and operations such as "get the path from this filename", "get the relative path from the absolute path", etc.

Comment: i think as i have stated, creating an absrtaction around the physical file system and always use that (always coding against the interface) throughout your app. then just use dependency injection to propogate through your test subject. i know it's monotonous work but as programmers we have to do these things to gain a clean separation of concerns and allow for ease of testability :)

Comment: You are really not getting what is being asked here. If I'm looking for a fake file system, it must be because I *already* have made an abstraction of the whole file system in my app (as stated in a comment of the OP). I *just* need a fake implementation of the file system to use in my tests..

Comment: sorry mate, maybe i have misunderstood. but as you say, all the operations are simple and there cannot be such a large array of methods you need, it would not take very long to write a fake file system. if you found one off the shelf so to speak, you would need to write some adaptor so that it may interface with your already abstracted file system; on top of learning this new fake system. it may be false economy to avoid writing it yourself. write one and open source it to help those in your situation in future ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[ShrinkWrap from the Arquillian project](http://arquillian.org/modules/shrinkwrap-shrinkwrap/) looks to include a NIO compliant in memory FileSystem

You can create a simple in memory FileSystem by doing the following:

```
FileSystem fs = ShrinkWrapFileSystems.newFileSystem(ShrinkWrap.create(GenericArchive.class))
```

Comment: Does it support file:// protocol, can't find documentation....

Answer (score 1):

Two other in memory file systems for java are,

[memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem)

[ephemeralfs](https://github.com/sbridges/ephemeralfs)

Both implement the NIO.2 File system api.

Answer (score 0):

I was googling "Fake java FileSystem" and found this question. Unfortunately this is all I found. So I wrote this fake FileSystem myself: https://github.com/dernasherbrezon/mockfs

I'm using it for simulating IOExceptions during read/write to files. IOException could happen for example due to "no disk space", which is nearly impossible to simulate by other means.

Answer (score -1):

Its a bit old and this solution seems to be linux only but it looks good
https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tmpfs%20on%20ubuntu

**tmpfs** is an in-memory mapped directory (data disappears on reboot). Once mounted, Data can be copied into it and be worked on from memory.