# Java virtual file system application

Tags: java, filesystems, directory, virtual

Good day, everyone,

I need to make a *virtual Java file system*. It means that all the modifications on this system are not reflected on real OS - so if user creates, moves, deletes, copies files and directories in program, it just imitates the file system and its structure and nothing more. As the initial point we have the root of the file system, kept in program memory - virtual "C:". The user can write command "**create directory C:\text**" or "**delete file C:\test2\myfile.txt**". At any time you can print the tree of created virtual directories and files.

What is the best way to do it? Or where I can find how real file systems work?

P.S. I thought of organizing directories as lists, and files as simple strings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [a few ideas](http://web.archive.org/web/20061128034903/http://mindprod.com/projects/javafilesystem.html). For the commands, I'd follow the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) specification (mkdir, ls, chmod, etc.), so that users won't be bothered with unknown commands (and you have a track of what needs to be done).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any Fake File System frameworks for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970192/are-there-any-fake-file-system-frameworks-for-java)

Comment: Do you *need* it or do you need to *create* it? Like, for a homework?

Comment: I'd use byte arrays rather than strings for the underlying files. That would be closer to how existing file systems work.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the [Commons Virtual File System](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) library.

Comment: I don't think Commons VFS provides what OP is looking for. It's an abstraction layer that presents a uniform view of a wide range of existing storage systems. It does not provide an in-memory storage system itself.

Comment: OP could either use the in-memory database if this is a possibility or implement his own FS implementation for VSF.

Comment: Well, the question is, in fact, how to "implement his own FS implementation", so this seems to leave OP where he started.

Comment: Yes but VFS would provide a good framework for that(managing the structure for you). The ram implementation would be a good starter.

Answer (score 1):

You can have this kind of format

```
public class Directory{

private List<File> files;


// geters and setters
// add more propertied to directory if required
```

}

```
 public class File{

private String name;
private int size;
private Date cretedDate;

// add more properties
  }
```

Comment: I would not use different classes. Use a class node and add all necessary members. Like listSubNodes, parent, isFile, isDirectory and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can use is [Google's in memory file system implementation for java](https://github.com/google/jimfs) which implements Java's [FileSystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

User jnrfuse, supporting crossplatform

Example usage:

https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/serce/jnrfuse/examples/MemoryFS.java